# How to implement Sidebar for macOS in Swift?

Tags: macos, sidebar, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to implement a sidebar like the one used in the macOS Notes app. I've got the storyboard and sidebar working. But how can I implement the content window / detail view on the right? I want to show something based on the selection made in the sidebar. I tried doing it by hiding stuff in one view but it gets messy real quick. I'd rather switch views in the same window somehow. What is the commonly accepted way of doing this?

[image: Example layout]

Comment: `NSSplitView`/`NSSplitViewController`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify. Yes it is a NSSplitViewController with two Split View Items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OSX Storyboard : communicate between NSViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182956/mac-osx-storyboard-communicate-between-nsviewcontroller)

Comment: Easy solution: Use borderless NSTabViewController on the right side and change tab when your selection changes. Alternatively look for Apple sample app called Lister https://github.com/beansmile/Lister it has example for macOS as well.